# cannot be referenced from a static context error in java

Tags: java

I have a function as follows:

```
public String [] splitString(String text) {

     int linebreaks=text.length()/80; //how many linebreaks do I need?  
     String [] newText = new String[linebreaks+1];       
     String tmpText = text;
     String [] parts = tmpText.split(" "); //save each word into an array-element

     //split each word in String into a an array of String text. 
     StringBuffer [] stringBuffer = new StringBuffer[linebreaks+1]; //StringBuffer is necessary because of manipulating text
     int i=0; //initialize counter 
     int totalTextLength=0;
     for(int k=0; k<linebreaks+1;k++) {
         stringBuffer[k] = new StringBuffer();
         while(true) {               
             if (i>=parts.length) break; //avoid NullPointerException
             totalTextLength=totalTextLength+parts[i].length(); //count each word in String              
             if (totalTextLength>80) break; //put each word in a stringbuffer until string length is >80
             stringBuffer[k].append(parts[i]);
             stringBuffer[k].append(" ");
             i++;
         }
         //reset counter, save linebreaked text into the array, finally convert it to a string 
         totalTextLength=0; 
         newText[k] = stringBuffer[k].toString();
     }
     return newText;
 }
```

I am calling the function from another function and doing some calculations as follows:

```
String text = "abc";
String [] tmpText = splitString(text);
for( int k=0;k<tmpText.length;k++) {
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx, texty);
    contentStream.drawString(tmpText[k]); 
    contentStream.endText();
    texty = texty - 20;
}           
contentStream.setLineWidth((float) 0.25);
```

I am getting an error in this line 'String [] tmpText = splitString(text);' like this:cannot be referenced from a static context. What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: That seccond method is that in a static method?

Comment: Do an effort and search for your error. Stack Overflow is filled with questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

A `static` method can only call other `static` methods, so you need to define `splitString` as such too:

```
public static String[] splitString(String text) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The other method is `static` while the `splitString` is not.

Declare `splitString` as static and it should work:

```
public static String[] splitString(String text) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your splitString method static so it can be referenced in a static context.

```
public static String[] splitString(String text)
```